# Foldl return a Tuple in SML?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, smlnj

The problem I'm working on needs to take in a list of integers and return the average of those numbers.  It needs to fit a specific format that looks like this...

```
fun average (n::ns) =
let
val (a,b) = fold? (?) ? ?
in
real(a) / real(b)
end;
```

I'm only allowed to replace the question marks and cannot used any built in functions.  I have a working solution, but it doesn't adhere to these rules.

```
fun average (n::ns) =
    let
        val (a,b) = ((foldl (fn(x, y)=>(x+y)) n ns), length(ns)+1)
    in
        real(a) / real(b)
    end;
```

So, is there a way to make a fold function return a tuple?  Something like this is what I want it to do, but obviously I can't do this...

```
val (a,b) = ((foldl (fn(x, y)=>(x+y), count++) n ns)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return type of `foldl` is the type of the initial accummulator. So the idea here is to provide a tuple including sum and count of elements in the list:

```
fun average (n::ns) =
    let
        val (a, b) = foldl (fn (x, (sum, count)) => (sum+x, count+1)) (n, 1) ns
    in
        real(a) / real(b)
    end
```

Notice that your solution fails if the list is empty, it's better to add another case of handling empty list (either returning 0.0 or throwing a custom exception):

```
fun average [] = 0.0
  | average (n::ns) = (* the same as above *)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I see what you're saying about the empty list.  That aside, I'm getting this error now...  Error: operator and operand don't agree [overload]
  operator domain: ('Z * int) * 'Z -> 'Z
  operand:         ('Z * int) * 'Z -> 'Z * int

Comment: @MCR: See my update, I have corrected the order of arguments.

Comment: Thank you.  Works great and makes a lot of sense now.